# popup menu resize height and width

Tags: android, popup

I wanna increase the width of my popup menu, when i click on menu button it open in the corner and small in size, I want to increase its size from small to the both ends.

here is my code of popup menu,

```
        ivmainmenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(Home.this,ivmainmenu);
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popupmenu,popup.getMenu());

            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.ourwork:

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this,Ourwork.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intent);

                        break;

                    case R.id.aboutus:

                        Intent intent2= new Intent(Home.this,Aboutus.class);
                        startActivity(intent2);

                        break;

                    case R.id.services:

                        Intent intent3= new Intent(Home.this,Services.class);
                        startActivity(intent3);
                        break;
                    case R.id.contact:

                        Intent intent4= new Intent(Home.this,Contact.class);
                        startActivity(intent4);
                        break;
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            });

            popup.show();
        }
    });
```

this is my way it looks,

[image]

I want it in the full widht and below the alfadesign logo, can it possible?

please help me regarding these,
thank you.

Comment: i don't think you can set `layout:width` , so you might have to create your own view layout and load that layout into `PopWindow` and display that `PopWindow` at `specific position`

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567472/change-the-height-of-the-action-bar-overflow-menu-items-via-styles

Comment: can i have the xml for it?

Comment: how can i define that xml on popup menu?

Comment: for create custom popup menu please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329132/android-custom-dropdown-popup-menu

Comment: that I have done but I want to resize my window....

Comment: can I have any answer for this?

Comment: <style name="PopupMenu" parent="PopupMenu">
<item name="listPreferredItemHeightSmall">40dp</item>
</style>
In your style.xml use this to set height of popupmenu