# Change the height of the toolbar overflow menu list

Tags: android, android-menu

How to resize the height of overflow menu list? Currently it extends till the bottom of the activity. I tried adding a style as follows,

```
<style name="CustomMenu" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:maxHeight">150dp</item>
</style>
```

and added this theme to app theme

```
<style name="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/CustomMenu</item>
</style>
```

This doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line in style:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">72dp</item>
</style>
```

Its look like similar like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567472/change-the-height-of-the-action-bar-overflow-menu-items-via-styles)

You have to look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044370/reduce-menu-items-width-height-and-textview-size) also.

Comment: Both the questions attached are not relevant to my question as they are about the menu **item** height and mine is about **whole menu list** height.